# Angular9/rxjs6.5: How to Transform an Array of Observable Object Array to an Observable Object Property Array?

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular9, rxjs6, switchmap

I'm using Angular(9) Powered Bootstrap (ng-bootstrap 6.1) and am providing ngbTypeahead with an Observable<IKeyValue[]> like so:

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    return text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      // switchMap allows returning an observable rather than maps array
      switchMap((searchText) => {
        if (!searchText || searchText.trim().length < 3) {
          // when the user erases the searchText
          return EMPTY;
        } else {
          // get a list of dealer reps
          return this.myService.getKeyValues(searchText);
        }
      })
      , catchError((error) => of(this.myService.postErrorMessage(error)))
    );
  }
```

I need to transform the output of this.myService.getKeyValues from Observable<IKeyValue[]> to Observable<string[]> by mapping each IKeyValue item to its item.value property.

How do I modify the code above to do that using rxjs 6.5.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the switchMap, you can put a [map()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) operator, do the transformation you need and return the new value.

It would be something along those lines I think. Note the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in the return value is a different one.

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
return text$.pipe(
  debounceTime(200),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  // switchMap allows returning an observable rather than maps array
  switchMap((searchText) => {
    if (!searchText || searchText.trim().length < 3) {
      // when the user erases the searchText
      return EMPTY;
    } else {
      // get a list of dealer reps
      return this.myService.getKeyValues(searchText);
    }
  }),
  map((response: IKeyValue[]) => { //Input parameter is the result from the switchMap
      //I'll do it with a map on the array to retrieve how you want the array by mapping only the property, but you can do in some other way.
      return response.map(item => item.value);
  }),
  catchError((error) => of(this.myService.postErrorMessage(error)))
);
```

}

Comment: I need the syntax for this particular case.  That's what is eluding me.

Comment: I've tried to attach the following snippet in several ways and it always results in a type violation: `.map((li: IKeyValue) => of(li.value))`

Comment: I have edited my response with an example from your code @CAK2